# Strange one: Text in website on Android is scrambled, looks hacked, but isn't

Tags: android, wordpress, fonts, render

Got a strange one.

http://reaganhayes.com/finishes/

Displays text normally in other browsers, including iPad and iPhone, but on my Android phone it's showing the menu text and the Headings as garbage text, like "crokfpefkdp" and "d^iibov"

Here's a screenshot: http://reaganhayes.com/temp/android_text.png

In the Chrome inspector, looking at the source, the text is normal "About", "Contact", etc. I used Adobe's Edge Inspect to inspect the phone's browser and it shows normal words in the source.

I tried it on two different Android phones with the same result. My phone is a Samsung Vibrant running FROYO.UVKA6

I assumed it was a font character-mapping issue because the same word in the menu and in the headings had the same garbage text, but when I stripped out all fonts and only used Arial, it had the same results. I tried that with the actual CSS for the site, and also via the Chrome inspector.

Charset is standard UTF-8.

The Wordpress theme is a modified version of the Wordpress 2012 theme.

W3 Total Cache was running previously, but I've deactivated it while I solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Kenny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to change text rendering method in your style.css.

From:

```
body {
…
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
…
}
```

To:

```
body {
…
text-rendering: auto;
…
}
```

`OptimizeLegibility` method is broken on Android Froyo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfecto. Thank you @Dima, you nailed it.